# Query Parameter Use in Valence

Tags: api, desire2learn, valence

I was trying to retrieve an assessment using Valence however an unsure about how to attach the Query Parameters

[Assessment API](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/assessment.html#get--d2l-api-le-(version)-(orgUnitId)-assessment)

I've tried attaching it as data in the ajax call, as well as GET parameters in the URL.

```
$.ajax({
'd2l/api/le/1.0/61399/assessment',
    {
        method:'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-Csrf-Token': localStorage['XSRF.Token']
        },
        data: {
            assessmentType: 'Rubric',
            objectType: 'Dropbox',
            objectId: 559230,
            userId:97197
        }
    }
}).done(function(data){console.log(data););
```

Am I going about it wrong somewhere? There is a typo in the API for the first parameter -assessmentType vs asssessmentType.... but I'm assuming it is supposed to be spelled the correct way.

Thanks in advance for your assistance :)

Comment: Note that the route you're attempting to use is a available only in the special `unstable` API contract, so you can't expect the route to exist in the `1.0` contract version as your code seems to imply you're doing. The path to that call should actually be more like `d2l/api/le/unstable/61399/assessment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everywhere I've gotten GET parameters to work in the API have been on the url:

d2l/api/le/1.0/61399/assessment?assessmentType=Rubric&objectType=Dropbox&objectId=559230&userId=97197

but I tried this on my system with one of my own rubrics on a dropbox assignment and I get nothing back. The API docs do say that this is an unstable route, so that may be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a call the *path* of the route gets used as part of the base-string for the authentication token generation, but the *query parameters* do not. Still, when you make the call, you attach the query parameters on the URL just as you would with any parameterized request. So, the call might be

```
GET https://yourLMS.edu?assessmentType=Rubric&objectType=Dropbox&objectId=559230&userId=97197
```

But for the purposes of generating your security tokens, you form the base string with `GET`, `/d2l/api/le/1.0/61399/assessment`, and the timestamp.